# Need Performance Comparison AsyncQueryHandler vs CursorLoader Android

Tags: android, multithreading, performance

Explain in detail performance about asyncqueryhandler vs cursorloader. Which one is best for development.
Other than Code optimization, Is there any details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody I know uses `AsyncQueryHandler`. You should use `CursorLoader` and leverage the `Loader` framework -- it does more than simply move your queries to the background, it also provides better handling of delivering results when you go through configuration changes.

Comment: see http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/search?q=&defs=&refs=AsyncQueryHandler&path=&hist=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=prebuilts&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools

Comment: @pskink From above link what are you trying to convey